# iOS 8 Share Extension not working on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I have creat a new target Share Extension in xcode , 
then I run it on my device.
I don't know why when I run my Share Extension on my devices (iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6) the won't show.
Pls help me! Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

1. I have creat New/Target/ Share Extension
   [image]
2. I run it with app Notes on my device and then my extension not show 
   [image]

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you have done in more detail, and how you have attempted to test it. There are lots of reasons why it might not work. Give us some way to figure out which one(s) might apply here.

Comment: Show us how you have set up and created your share extension

Answer (score 43):

I had the same issue and I solved it with changing the "Deployment Target" of the extension to a value below the iOS version of my device.

Yes, an extension has its own deployment target!

Comment: During development of my project the latest iOS version had increased. When adding the extension to the project it took the latest target which was indeed higher than installed on my test device. Setting it to the same version solved my issue.

Comment: I got the solutions form above answer.