# Ios share extension does not work when installed by testflight but works installed by xcode

Tags: ios, testflight, share-extension

Installed with testflight the application does appear in the list of target applications to share an image with. When I select my application icon in the list I do get a normal Post dialog. After pressing "Post" in the dialog the application does open but nothing else happens.

When the same version of application is installed with xcode the shared file is delivered and the application displays the shared image.

I am not even sure how to debug such an issue as the application installed by testflight does not appear in the list of installed applications in xcode Devices window. Nothing that I can find in device logs either.

Please suggest any approach to troubleshooting the issue.

**Update:** I found a way to get much more detailed logs from device than the one provided by xcode's "Devices" window: [deviceconsole](https://github.com/cbowns/deviceconsole) utility. This gives at least some information to approach troubleshooting.

**Update 1:** It turns out that the application installed through ad hoc ipa file exported from the same archive that was submitted to testflight shows the same problem. This allows much quicker testing turn around.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31516372) indicates that the problem can be caused by "Deployment Target" of extension set above the ios version of test device. I did try different combination of this setting in the application and extension, nothing helped thus far.

**Update 2:** I created code-level support request with apple for this issue and provided full source of the application to them. After few months of apathetic communications they concluded that the problem is due to a bug and suggested to create report Apple Bug Reporter. I did that and after another few months of more apathetic communications the issue was promptly closed on the basis that the application does not crash. Frustrating, but I still need to resolve the problem, now looks like without help from vendor.

Answer (score 1):

If the deployment target is higher than the version number of the actual phone, your code cannot run. So the only choice is reducing the deployment target of the extension to be the same as the app.

I’d check if you have somehow set different deployment targets for debug and release.